# Maximum number of concurrent NSURLConnections to the same host?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I'm running in to an issue in an OS X app that creates multiple, persistent connections to the same host using NSURLConnection. I create a separate connection for different rooms, and it stays connected the entire time the room is open to consume a streaming API. When opening many rooms, it stops working correctly.

I created a separate sample app that creates 10 connections, and it seems to only allow 6 connections to work, and the others are queued. Does anyone know if there is a way to override this limit? I can't find it documented anywhere. The only workaround I've found is it seems to be per host name, so testing with "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" allows 6 connections per host. I uploaded a sample project with client and server here - http://cl.ly/1x3K0D1F072V3U2T0C0I.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that, this is on OS X. Updated question.

Comment: @Zach Waugh
I am checking your code :) Are you sure it isn't something to do with your server.js?(Node) i ran your server.js but i am also getting maximum 6 connections.

Comment: It could be, I don't know node.js well. But this is also happening with a different server not under my control. I wrote that client/server to try to reproduce in the simplest case.

Comment: NSURLConnection is meant for URL loading, for building simple clients to request-response servers, not for persistent connections. So it implicitly handles high-level things (that the web browser would take care of, if you were doing the same thing in JS), like "only allow N simultaneous outgoing connections, M to the same host" so you don't have to worry about them. Instead of fighting against what it's designed for, you probably want to use a better-suited API.

Comment: Hey Zach, I'm running into something similar but unrelated on iOS. If I have a slow connection and hit the same endpoint multiple times, it seems to max out at 5 connections. I'm trying to figure out the cause as well. One question I have for you: have you tried https? The limit seems to go away for me when I'm hitting an https endpoint.

Comment: @jasongregori I also experience limit of five. I'm not sure why you'd ever want more, as there are diminishing returns beyond 4 (but serious server implications).

Comment: @Rob more just a limit I'd like to know about. I found out on iOS the connections can be going to any endpoint but still max out at 5 (see my new answer to this question). So if you had some bad slow endpoint it could stop all your other calls. Makes you realize that you should **really** be using AFNetworking!

Comment: Does AFNetworking overcome that limit? Is it not using NSURLConnection underneath it's requests?

Comment: AFNetworking is using `NSURLConnection` behind the scenes. _And_ the described scenario is not an appropriate scenario for HTTP anyhow. So that's not an issue with the client libraries, it's the issue with the intention of the author.

Answer (score 5):

I filed a Radar for something that seems like the same issue but on iOS. I found that you can't have more than 5 connections open at once. The connections don't have to be pointing to the same domain. Anything after that would be queued. So if you have 5 connections open to an extremely slow endpoint, any other connections will not go through.

Radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2542401

Apple's reply:

> This is the effect of our NSURLConnection connection cache. It is expected. We expect to address this type of configuration with new API.

I asked if they could give me anymore information (does it vary? does the type of connection affect it?) and they said:

> Unfortunately, we can't give details about the connection limit behavior.
>
> User agents in general (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) use six simultaneous TCP connections per hostname, with potential one-offs.

Answer (score 0):

You could break this limitation by using CFNetwork API (CFHTTPMessage).

Here is the CFNetwork Programming Guide.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132

BTW, if you decide to use CFNetwork, you'll need to work around the proxy and authenticate.

Wish this could helped!