# Is there connection limit of NSURLConnection in Mac Cocoa Application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsurlconnection, limit, progress

I am trying to build a multiple-connection based and continuous download module with Objective-C.

I set up a new NSThread to handle events(such as connection:didReceivedData:) of NSURLConnection. but I found that my download is not that fast than my test on pc.

When I loged some info of my module, I found that only 6 connection received data from server even though I started 60 connections.

After I tested on windows PC, I found its connection count is much bigger than 6.

So I wrote another test app to test whether I could set up some connection in another app when my download module is running.

I programmed create 100 connections in main thread and 100 connections in background thread, block thread quit with `[[NSRunLoop currentLoop] run];`, store connections which has data arrival in a shared NSMutableSet using lock to avoid resource conflict, dump this mutable set every second.

Then I found that there is still 6 live connection (which has data arrival) in the mutable set.

So I believed there is a limit of the count of NSURLConnection per single progress in Mac/Cocoa.

I want know how can I make the limit more bigger such as 20 or other?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I read about php sessions blocking http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/ but this isn't the case for me. My scripts just sleeps for 2 secs then exits.

Comment: you have seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853852/maximum-number-of-concurrent-nsurlconnections-to-the-same-host

Answer (score 0):

We could break this limitation by using CFNetwork API (CFHTTPMessage).

Here is the CFNetwork Programming Guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132

BTW, if you decide to use CFNetwork, you'll need to work around the proxy and authenticate.