# Measuring response time in AFNetworking on multithreaded app

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, afnetworking, load-testing

**UPDATE**

After some research I made some improvement to my code. I first replace each place I measured the time using: `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];` with atomic time measurements such as: `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();`

I noticed that didn't made any difference. Checking with our server guy I noticed that the server show impressive results - which make me think the bottleneck here is not the server but my laptop/some other point in the way.

---

**Original post**

I'm trying to load test my server so I built a scenario that mimic a user flow in the app. This flow contains about 11-17 calls to the server, and some of them have to be synchronous (as the user won't be able to reach to a certain screen unless he go through some other screen).

I then ran this scenario using `X` threads simultaneously, trying to stress the server and see where are the weakest links. In order to analyse the info, I logged some relevant info to a file each time a response is coming back (either on success or on failure), and noticed some very weird stuff is going on with the timing of each call.

To measure the time of a call I measured the start time of each call just before I fire it using:

```
 test.startTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
//fire the request
[operation start];
```

And the first thing that happen in the success/failure blocks is:

Success

```
void (^successWrapper)  (AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    //#################TEST ANALYTICS###############
    NSDate *endTime = [NSDate date];
    test.endTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[endTime timeIntervalSince1970]];
    test.lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(test.endTime.doubleValue - test.startTime.doubleValue)];
    //##############################################

   //Some other success stuff...

   };
```

Failure:

```
void (^failureWrapper) (AFHTTPRequestOperation *, NSError *) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

   //#################TEST ANALYTICS###############
   NSDate *endTime = [NSDate date];
   test.endTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[endTime timeIntervalSince1970]];
   test.lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(test.endTime.doubleValue - test.startTime.doubleValue)];
   //##############################################

   //Some other failure stuff...

   };
```

Yet, I'm experiencing very high latency in the log file, and it getting worse as `X` is getting bigger and bigger.

I assume the problem happens due to context switches between threads but i'm not sure about it. So my questions is: **How can I measure properly the response time of each call in `AFNetworking` in a system with many threads**?

Some notes:

- As mentioned above, some of the calls can happen simultaneously while other have to happen sequentially.
- `X` should eventually be really high (>10000).

Thanks!

Comment: At 10,000 threads you will see significant overhead, I suggest limiting your test application to a handful at most.

Comment: @SamMiller, Well - I'm having those high numbers at 100 threads (and even less), not to talk about 10000...

Comment: @goldengil, you should be using < 20 threads, not around 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a limited number of `NSURLConnection` network requests that can run concurrently. You can start however many operations you want, but `NSURLConnection` will only run a limited number concurrently (4-6, I believe, depending upon OS version). The subsequent `NSURLConnection` requests will wait for prior ones to finish. In extreme situations (e.g. submitting hundreds of requests), this can even result in the latter requests timing out (unless you specify a sufficiently large timeout parameter). This constraint is not one of network latency, but rather an artifact of the limited number of concurrent requests imposed by the OS on the client.

In client-side apps, when using an `NSOperationQueue`-based framework like AFNetworking, you handle this limitation by not starting the operations yourself, but merely adding them to an `NSOperationQueue`. You can then constrain the operation queue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to some reasonable number that corresponds to the number of concurrent `NSURLConnection` requests (e.g. I might suggest 5) that can run at any given time to eliminate this appearance of latency within the individual operations. If you're adding these requests to your own queue, you'd specify `maxConcurrentOperationCount` for that queue. If you're using `AFHTTPRequstOperationManager`, you'd do this on the `operationQueue` property of the manager.

If you want to benchmark the performance of AFNetworking in the above context, the question is whether you're looking to measure the total elapsed time (in which case you can capture the start time when you add it to the queue and then calculate the elapsed time in the completion block, similar to how you outlined in your question) or whether you're looking to capture the time actually spent running the operation.

If you're interested in the latter, you really want to start the timer when the operation queue results in the `start` method being called, which you can do either add observers for the  `AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification` and `AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification` notifications, or just fork AFNetworking and modify `AFURLConnectionOperation` to calculate the elapsed time for you.

Finally, it's a little unclear as to whether your question was really stress testing the app, or stress testing the server. If simply stress testing the app, the above should work. If you want to stress test the server to simulate many simultaneous users, that's more difficult and probably would entail either bypassing `NSURLConnection`/AFNetworking altogether (with `CFNetwork` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21932371/1271826)) or really setting up a collection of physical devices/computers and have them do their client-side AFNetworking stress tests simultaneously.